# Finding the date range of a date in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have three dataframes:

```
df_1 = 

     Name    Description           Date         Quant      Value 
 0   B100        text123     2021-01-02             3       89.1
 1   B101        text567     2021-01-03             2       90.1
 2   A200        text820     2021-03-02             1       90.2
 3   B101        text567     2021-03-02             6       90.2
 4   A500        text758     2021-03-06             1       94.0
 5   A500        text758     2021-03-06             2       94.0
 6   A500        text758     2021-03-07             2       94.0
 7   A200        text820     2021-04-02             1       90.2
 8   A999        text583     2021-05-05             2       90.6
 9   A998        text834     2021-05-09             1       99.9

df_2 = # the index is funny because I did some manipulations and dropped some NaNs before
       Code     Name     Person
  0    900      B100        600
  1    901      B100        610
  2    959      B101        670
  3    979      A999        670
  6    944      A200        388
  7    921      A500        663
  8    988      B300        794

df_3 =

     Code        StartDate       EndDate      RealValue
0     900       2000-01-01    2007-12-31           80.9
1     901       2008-01-01    2099-12-31           98.8
2     902       2000-01-01    2020-02-02           98.3
3     903       2000-01-01    2007-01-10           90.6
4     903       2007-01-11    2099-12-31           90.7
5     959       2020-04-09    2099-12-31           98.9
6     979       2000-01-01    2009-02-12           87.6
7     979       2009-02-13    2021-06-13           78.0
8     979       2021-06-15    2099-12-31           89.5
9     944       2020-04-09    2099-12-31           98.9
10    921       2020-04-09    2099-12-31           98.9
```

I want to do the following:

Start from `df_1`, find the corresponding `Code(s)` in `df_2` for each `Name` in `df_1`. Now I look into `df_1` to see what the `Value` and `Quant` were at every `Date`, and I compare the `Value` with every `RealValue` from the date range where my `Date` is. The difficult part is selecting the right Code and then the right data range. So:

```
Name         Date   Code     Value      RealValue     Quant
B100   2021-01-02    901      89.1           98.8         3
B101   2021-01-03    959      90.1           98.9         2
A200   2021-03-02    944      90.2           98.9         1
B101   2021-03-02    959      90.1           98.9         6
A500   2021-03-06    921      94.0           98.9         1
A500   2021-03-06    921      94.0           98.9         2
A500   2021-03-07    921      94.0           98.9         2
A200   2021-05-05    944      90.2           98.9         2
A999   2021-05-05    979      90.6           78.0         2
```

What I did was merging everything in one table, but since my real dataset is huge and there are many records that do not appear everywhere, I might have lost some data or ended up with NaNs. So I would leave the dataframes as they are here and navigate through them for every record in `df_1`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
start_date = "2019-1-1"
end_date="2019-1-31"

after_start_dates=df['date']>= start_date
before_star_dates=df['date']<= end_date

between_date=after_start_dates & before_end_dates
filter_dates=df.loc[between_dates]

print(filtered_dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, map `Name` column from `df2` to `df3` then merge `df1` and `df3` on `Name` column. Finally, filter out rows where `Date` is between `StartDate` and `EndDate`:

```
COLS = df1.columns.tolist() + ['RealValue']

df3['Name'] = df3['Code'].map(df2.set_index('Code')['Name'])

out = df1.merge(df3, on='Name', how='left') \
         .query('Date.between(StartDate, EndDate)')[COLS]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    Name Description        Date  Quant  Value  RealValue
1   B100     text123  2021-01-02      3   89.1       98.8
2   B101     text567  2021-01-03      2   90.1       98.9
3   A200     text820  2021-03-02      1   90.2       98.9
4   B101     text567  2021-03-02      6   90.2       98.9
5   A500     text758  2021-03-06      1   94.0       98.9
6   A500     text758  2021-03-06      2   94.0       98.9
7   A500     text758  2021-03-07      2   94.0       98.9
8   A200     text820  2021-04-02      1   90.2       98.9
10  A999     text583  2021-05-05      2   90.6       78.0
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' on the last code line. Might it be because I might have some strings in my df3 and the RealValue column is of type object?

Comment: So when I print the second code line, I have a lot of NaNs as "Name", might this be a problem? In the sample of my original post there are some Names that only appear in one of the dataframes.

Comment: First, in df3, do you see `Name` as a new column?

Comment: in the original one no, in the one that you output yes, and many of the values are NaN but that should not be a problem...

Comment: there are NaNs even in the EndDate

Comment: Try step by step: `out = df1.merge(df3, on='Name', how='left')` works?

Comment: *there are NaNs even in the EndDate*: do you mean before the mapping of Name?

Comment: yes there were NaNs in the original data but I filled them in and still got the error. As for the mini step you mentioned, yes it works. So the problem is when doing the data range thing.

Comment: Now try: `df1.merge(df3, on='Name', how='left').query('Date.between(StartDate, EndDate)')`

Comment: this is where I get the error above.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `out.head(10)` -> `out = df1.merge(df3, on='Name', how='left')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try1 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on = 'Name', how = 'outer')
try2 = pd.merge(try1, df_3, on = 'Code', how = 'outer')
try2
```

and then, you try to navigate in try2.

```
try2[['Name','Date','Code','Value','RealValue','Quant']]
```